# validate presence of fields from another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, activerecord, model

**I try to validate the presence of attributes that belong to another model, to no avail.**

Having

- User Model
- Profile Model

Using this form:

```
= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' }   , :validate => true , :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f|

= f.input :username,                  :label  => t(:username)
= f.input :email,                     :label  => t(:email),
                                      :hint   => t(:hint_email_visible)
= f.input :password,                  :label  => t(:password), :require => true
= f.input :password_confirmation,     :label  => t(:password_confirm)

- resource.build_profile
= f.fields_for :profile do |f|

 #render
   = f.hidden_field :form, :value => "signup"

    .clear
    = f.input :gender,
              :label => t(:your_gender),
              :collection => gender,
              :item_wrapper_class => 'inline',
              :as => :radio_buttons


.clear
= f.button :submit, t(:submit, :scope => :register) + " »"
```

How Can I validate the presence of the gender field with above form setup?

Comment: Hi, Why don't you use accepts_nested_attributes_for in your code?

Comment: Could elaborate a bit more on that and perhaps supply a short example on how that should help?

Comment: http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1 may this link helps

Comment: Thx thats exactly what I need indeed, thx if you post it as reply instead of comment I can grand you the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May following code help you out.

controllers/users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
def new
    @user = User.new
    @user.build_profile
  end
end
```

models/users.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

models/profile.rb

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
   validates_presence_of :gender
end
```

may be you need to remove following line from view.

```
- resource.build_profile
```

Here is the link which you find helpful

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

Answer (score -1):

Although above is correct answer and I have implemented it like that, still the gender field doesent seem to validate at all. So kinda still in the same issue. Is it possible to re-open the question?